# Javascript path to directory

Tags: javascript, path, directory

This snippet of JavaScript opens all files in a folder located on the Desktop and named "test".

```
var inputFolder = Folder( Folder.desktop + '/test' ); // Make sure this is correct for your hard coded path!
```

How can I make it open the directory "test", located in D:/directory/directory2/ ?

Here is the full code, just in case someone will needed. It opens all psd files in a directory.

```
var inputFolder = Folder( Folder.desktop + '/test' ); // Make sure this is correct for    your hard coded path???

var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(psd)$/i);

for ( var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {

   app.open( fileList[i] );

     };
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please define `Folder`, it is not a native function.

Comment: I am not very good with scripting... :) I only know that in the above form the script works... I just want to change the path to the directory...

Comment: ^ How are we supposed to help you then? You must have somewhat of a working knowledge of the code and language in question. What you're basically saying right now is "here's something I haven't put any effort into trying to understand - fix it".

Comment: Is this a Photoshop script or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `Folder.desktop` with the path to whereever you want it to go. For your example above, try:

```
var inputFolder = Folder('D://directory/directory2' + '/test' );    
var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(psd)$/i);    
for ( var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {    
   app.open( fileList[i] );    
   };
```

This will open all files with the extension .psd located in the directory **D:\directory\directory2\test**.

Comment: Why is the path " D:// " and not just " D:/ " ?